# In gtk-rs, how do I get the current screen that a gtk::Window is (mostly) on?

Tags: rust, gtk, gtk-rs

What I'm trying to accomplish is to calculate the dpi (or, in my case, the dpmm) of the screen that my application is mostly on. So far as I know, the modern way to do that is to call `gdk::Monitor::get_height_mm` and `gdk::Monitor::get_width_mm`.

So, starting with `window: gtk::Window`, I'm trying to get the Monitor like so:

```
let screen = window.get_display().and_then(|display| get_monitor_at_window(&window));
```

But, `gtk::Window` does not have an `IsA<gdk::Window>` implementation:

```
8 |     window.get_display().and_then(|display| display.get_monitor_at_window(&window));
  |                                                                           ^^^^^^^ the trait `glib::IsA<gdk::auto::window::Window>` is not implemented for `gtk::Window`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <gtk::Window as glib::IsA<glib::Object>>
            <gtk::Window as glib::IsA<gtk::Bin>>
            <gtk::Window as glib::IsA<gtk::Buildable>>
            <gtk::Window as glib::IsA<gtk::Container>>
          and 2 others
```

So, what is the path to get from `gtk::Window` to the millimeters of width and height for the screen that the window is on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`gtk::Window`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/struct.Window.html) is not the same as a [`gdk::Window`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gdk/struct.Window.html). The former is more like the concept of a "window", while the latter maps better to the concept of X windows. In other display protocols, these are also called "surfaces", which is why it got renamed in GTK 4, also to clear up this confusion.

In any case, to get the underlying surface/window of a widget in GTK, you can call the [`get_window()`](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.WidgetExt.html#tymethod.get_window) method on it (in gtk-rs, this is part of the [gtk::WidgetExt](https://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/trait.WidgetExt.html) trait)